# How to attach a boost::asio::tcp::io_stream to my io_service?

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I'm used to using [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html)s where I [construct](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/basic_stream_socket/overload1.html) them with an [`io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html). This has been useful because I have a single `io_service` for all sockets and these sockets share a threadpool.

Now, I'm trying to work with a [`boost::asio::ip::tcp::io_stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_iostream.html), and I'd like it perform all asynchronous work in the same threadpool. However, it does not appear to be possible to [construct](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_iostream/basic_socket_iostream.html) a `tcp::io_stream` with an external `io_service`.  The underlying socket does indeed use an internally initialized io_service.  Is there a way for me to continue using my centrally managed `io_service` with a `tcp::io_stream`?

I'm using boost version 1.62.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` object into the stream buffer:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daeb0f517fcd6f76)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    ba::io_service svc;
    tcp::socket s(svc);

    // e.g. connect to test service
    s.connect({{}, 6767});

    tcp::iostream stream;
    stream.rdbuf()->socket() = std::move(s);

    for (std::string line; getline(stream, line);) {
        std::reverse(line.begin(), line.end());
        stream << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When running against a netcat session on port 6767 that feeds:

```
This is
Not so bad
After all
```

The responses received are:

```
si sihT
dab os toN
lla retfA
```

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer, since there's no `socket()` method in `basic_socket_streambuf` prior to version 1.66.

Comment: @empty'void Interesting :) Perhaps OP upgraded.